# Tried reinstalling python on ubtuntu: dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, dpkg

I wanted to update python 3.8 to 3.10 but ran into some issues which is why I wanted to reinstall python, however, when removing it, I ran into even more issues and now I am unsure of what to do.
I am not experienced with ubuntu, but now my package manager system seems to be broken. When I try running commands such as, `apt-get install -f`, I get the following error.

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    3 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up python3-click (7.0-3) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-click.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
    dpkg: error processing package python3-click (--configure):
     installed python3-click package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
    Setting up python3-software-properties (0.99.9.8) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
    dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
     installed python3-software-properties package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
     software-properties-common depends on python3-software-properties (= 0.99.9.8); however:
      Package python3-software-properties is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-click
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I solve this problem? I just want python back and solve these problems.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/141370/how-to-fix-a-broken-package-when-apt-get-install-f-does-not-work